# Can't login system after massive upgrade

Tags: kali-linux

I installed a bunch of upgrades by running the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

with the result that I cannot even get to the login screen anymore  I am not sure what caused this. I have tried all the options provided in [this link](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26637-Can-t-login-after-the-upgrade-to-Kali-linux-2-0), but all without luck.

I have run out of ideas.

System info:

Linux kalik 4.8.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.15-1kali1 (2016-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux

More info:
(Please, ask for more information if that is needed)

History:

```
Start-Date: 2017-11-10  19:05:35
Commandline: apt-get remove wine
Remove: regripper:amd64 (2.5-1kali0), ollydbg:amd64 (1.10-1kali0), sqldict:amd64 (2.1-1kali0), wine:amd64 (1.8.6-1~bpo8+1)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  19:05:42

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  19:38:15
Commandline: apt-get -t jessie-backports install wine
Install: wine:amd64 (1.8.7-2~bpo8+1)
Upgrade: wine64:amd64 (1.8.6-1~bpo8+1, 1.8.7-2~bpo8+1), libwine:amd64 (1.8.6-1~bpo8+1, 1.8.7-2~bpo8+1)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  19:38:19

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  19:44:11
Commandline: apt-get install apt-transport-https
Install: libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (1.0.9.8.4, automatic), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.0.9.8.4)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  19:44:14

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  20:00:06
Commandline: apt-get remove wine
Remove: wine:amd64 (1.8.7-2~bpo8+1)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  20:00:07

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  20:04:00
Commandline: apt-get install wine-stable-amd64
Install: libgphoto2-port10:amd64 (2.5.4-1.1+b2, automatic), libgnutls-deb0-28:amd64 (3.3.8-6+deb8u7, automatic), libhogweed2:amd64 (2.7.1-5+deb8u2, automatic), libcapi20-3:amd64 (1:3.27-1, automatic), libnettle4:amd64 (2.7.1-5+deb8u2, automatic), wine-stable-amd64:amd64 (2.0.3~jessie), libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.50-2+deb8u3, automatic)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  20:04:04

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  20:07:27
Commandline: apt-get remove wine-stable-amd64
Remove: wine-stable-amd64:amd64 (2.0.3~jessie)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  20:07:27

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  20:07:51
Commandline: apt-get install wine
Install: wine:amd64 (1.8.7-2~bpo8+1)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  20:07:52

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  20:15:40
Commandline: apt-get remove wine
Remove: wine:amd64 (1.8.7-2~bpo8+1)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  20:15:41

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  20:36:13
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: postgresql-common:amd64 (178, 181~bpo8+1), postgresql-client-9.6:amd64 (9.6.1-2, 9.6.5-0+deb9u1~bpo8+1), manpages:amd64 (4.09-2, 4.10-2~bpo8+1), exim4-base:amd64 (4.88-4~bpo8+1, 4.89-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), python-pathlib2:amd64 (2.1.0-1, 2.2.0+really2.1.0-1~bpo8+1), erlang-public-key:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), liblapack3:amd64 (3.6.1-2, 3.7.0-1~bpo8+1), libgles2-mesa:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), libgphoto2-port12:amd64 (2.5.11-1, 2.5.12-1~bpo8+1), libcups2:amd64 (2.2.1-4, 2.2.1-8~bpo8+1), mesa-opencl-icd:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), erlang-os-mon:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.8.15-2~bpo8+2, 4.9.51-1~bpo8+1), libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.44+dfsg-2, 2.4.44+dfsg-5+deb9u1~bpo8+1), libgphoto2-6:amd64 (2.5.11-1, 2.5.12-1~bpo8+1), libwiretap6:amd64 (2.2.3+g57531cd-1, 2.2.4+gcc3dc1b-1~bpo8+1), libswresample2:amd64 (7:3.2.2-1, 7:3.2.5-1~bpo8+1), git-man:amd64 (1:2.11.0-2, 1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1), erlang-base:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), erlang-syntax-tools:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), openvpn:amd64 (2.4.0-3~bpo8+1, 2.4.0-6+deb9u1~bpo8+1), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), geoip-database-extra:amd64 (20161219-1, 20170512-1~bpo8+1), libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.15.2-2, 3.16.2-3~bpo8+1), erlang-tools:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), libgpg-error0:amd64 (1.26-1, 1.26-2~bpo8+1), erlang-eunit:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), geoip-database:amd64 (20161219-1, 20170512-1~bpo8+1), libwsutil7:amd64 (2.2.3+g57531cd-1, 2.2.4+gcc3dc1b-1~bpo8+1), git:amd64 (1:2.11.0-2, 1:2.11.0-3~bpo8+1), libgphoto2-l10n:amd64 (2.5.11-1, 2.5.12-1~bpo8+1), exim4-daemon-light:amd64 (4.88-2, 4.89-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), libxatracker2:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), libbrlapi0.6:amd64 (5.4-4, 5.4-7~bpo8+1), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), cups-common:amd64 (2.2.1-4, 2.2.1-8~bpo8+1), libpq5:amd64 (9.6.1-2, 9.6.5-0+deb9u1~bpo8+1), python-flask:amd64 (0.12-1, 0.12.1-1~bpo8+1), libpostproc54:amd64 (7:3.2.2-1, 7:3.2.5-1~bpo8+1), libvpx4:amd64 (1.6.0-3, 1.6.1-2~bpo8+1), erlang-runtime-tools:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), libgbm1:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), wireshark:amd64 (2.2.3+g57531cd-1, 2.2.4+gcc3dc1b-1~bpo8+1), python-cryptography:amd64 (1.7.1-2, 1.7.1-3~bpo8+1), libyara3:amd64 (3.5.0+dfsg-8, 3.5.0+dfsg-9~bpo8+1), sqlite3:amd64 (3.15.2-2, 3.16.2-3~bpo8+1), python-cffi-backend:amd64 (1.7.0-1, 1.9.1-2~bpo8+1), erlang-xmerl:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), libwscodecs1:amd64 (2.2.3+g57531cd-1, 2.2.4+gcc3dc1b-1~bpo8+1), libx264-148:amd64 (2:0.148.2728+git4d5c8b0-1, 2:0.148.2748+git97eaef2-1~bpo8+1), postgresql-9.6:amd64 (9.6.1-2, 9.6.5-0+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-snmp:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), exim4-config:amd64 (4.88-4~bpo8+1, 4.89-2+deb9u1~bpo8+1), erlang-ssl:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), libblas-common:amd64 (3.6.1-2, 3.7.0-1~bpo8+1), exfat-utils:amd64 (1.2.5-1, 1.2.5-2~bpo8+1), python-pygments:amd64 (2.1.3+dfsg-1, 2.2.0+dfsg-1~bpo8+1), libldap-common:amd64 (2.4.44+dfsg-2, 2.4.44+dfsg-5+deb9u1~bpo8+1), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), postgresql:amd64 (9.6+178, 9.6+181~bpo8+1), libgcrypt20:amd64 (1.7.5-2, 1.7.6-1~bpo8+1), libccid:amd64 (1.4.25-1, 1.4.26-1~bpo8+1), python-pkg-resources:amd64 (32.0.0-1, 33.1.1-1~bpo8+1), erlang-crypto:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), libjs-jquery-ui:amd64 (1.12.1+dfsg-3, 1.12.1+dfsg-4~bpo8+1), libavutil55:amd64 (7:3.2.2-1, 7:3.2.5-1~bpo8+1), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.32, 0.36~bpo8+1), erlang-mnesia:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), python3-pkg-resources:amd64 (32.0.0-1, 33.1.1-1~bpo8+1), dh-python:amd64 (2.20160818, 2.20170125~bpo8+1), usb-modeswitch-data:amd64 (20160803-1, 20170120-1~bpo8+1), python-setuptools:amd64 (32.0.0-1, 33.1.1-1~bpo8+1), postgresql-contrib-9.6:amd64 (9.6.1-2, 9.6.5-0+deb9u1~bpo8+1), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), libswscale4:amd64 (7:3.2.2-1, 7:3.2.5-1~bpo8+1), exfat-fuse:amd64 (1.2.5-1, 1.2.5-2~bpo8+1), libosmesa6:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), manpages-dev:amd64 (4.09-2, 4.10-2~bpo8+1), python-maxminddb:amd64 (1.2.2-1, 1.2.3-1~bpo8+1), ldap-utils:amd64 (2.4.44+dfsg-2, 2.4.44+dfsg-5+deb9u1~bpo8+1), libfftw3-double3:amd64 (3.3.5-1, 3.3.5-3~bpo8+1), fonts-wine:amd64 (1.8.6-1~bpo8+1, 1.8.7-2~bpo8+1), python-git:amd64 (2.1.0-1, 2.1.1-2~bpo8+1), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), cups-bsd:amd64 (2.2.1-4, 2.2.1-8~bpo8+1), libwireshark-data:amd64 (2.2.3+g57531cd-1, 2.2.4+gcc3dc1b-1~bpo8+1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), erlang-asn1:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1), libblas3:amd64 (3.6.1-2, 3.7.0-1~bpo8+1), libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.2.1-4, 2.2.1-8~bpo8+1), cups-client:amd64 (2.2.1-4, 2.2.1-8~bpo8+1), python-numpy:amd64 (1:1.12.0~b1-1, 1:1.12.1-2~bpo8+1), python-tornado:amd64 (4.4.2-1, 4.4.3-1~bpo8+1), libavresample3:amd64 (7:3.2.2-1, 7:3.2.5-1~bpo8+1), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (13.0.2-3, 13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2k-1~bpo8+1, 1.0.2l-1~bpo8+1), postgresql-client-common:amd64 (178, 181~bpo8+1), erlang-inets:amd64 (1:19.2.1+dfsg-1~bpo8+1, 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2~bpo8+1)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  20:38:06

Start-Date: 2017-11-10  21:34:26
Commandline: apt autoremove
Remove: libgphoto2-port10:amd64 (2.5.4-1.1+b2), libodbc1:amd64 (2.3.4-1), wine64:amd64 (1.8.7-2~bpo8+1), libosmesa6:amd64 (13.0.6-1~bpo8+1), libcapi20-3:amd64 (1:3.27-1), fonts-wine:amd64 (1.8.7-2~bpo8+1), libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.50-2+deb8u3), libwine:amd64 (1.8.7-2~bpo8+1)
End-Date: 2017-11-10  21:34:28

Start-Date: 2017-11-11  08:18:29
Commandline: apt dist-upgrade
Install: linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.4-amd64:amd64 (4.9.51-1~bpo8+1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-amd64:amd64 (4.8+77+kali1, 4.9+80+deb9u2~bpo8+1)
Remove: default-jdk:amd64 (2:1.8-57), openjdk-8-jdk:amd64 (8u111-b14-3), king-phisher:amd64 (1.4.0-0kali1), javasnoop:amd64 (1.1-rc2-1kali2)
End-Date: 2017-11-11  08:19:02
```

Output of `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
```

Output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   98304  3
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
vboxvideo              49152  1
ppdev                  20480  0
acpi_cpufreq           20480  0
joydev                 20480  0
ttm                    98304  1 vboxvideo
vboxguest             282624  1 vboxvideo
tpm_tis                16384  0
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 vboxvideo
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    45056  2 tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
snd_intel8x0           40960  0
snd_ac97_codec        126976  1 snd_intel8x0
snd_pcm               110592  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_intel8x0
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
evdev                  24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
drm                   360448  4 vboxvideo,ttm,drm_kms_helper
parport_pc             28672  0
sg                     32768  0
video                  40960  0
battery                16384  0
snd                    86016  4 snd_ac97_codec,snd_timer,snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
ac                     16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_ac97_codec
parport                49152  2 parport_pc,ppdev
button                 16384  0
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  585728  1
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  0
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
mbcache                16384  2 ext4
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
sr_mod                 24576  0
sd_mod                 45056  5
cdrom                  61440  1 sr_mod
ata_generic            16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  2
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
psmouse               135168  0
ahci                   36864  2
ohci_pci               16384  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ehci_pci               16384  0
ohci_hcd               53248  1 ohci_pci
i2c_piix4              24576  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
ehci_hcd               81920  1 ehci_pci
ata_piix               36864  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
usbcore               249856  7 usbhid,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ohci_pci,uas,ohci_hcd,ehci_pci
libata                249856  4 ahci,ata_piix,libahci,ata_generic
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
e1000                 143360  0
scsi_mod              225280  6 sd_mod,usb_storage,libata,uas,sr_mod,sg
fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: Kali Linux is a distribution specifically made for use by computer security professionals in the performance of their professional activities. It is **not** intended to be used as a general-purpose operating system.

Comment: @AlexP that might be true, but what has that to do with this question?

Comment: @AlexP are you referring to my use of wine or? :/

Comment: If that is the case, well, I am using wine for security testing purposes.

Comment: Actually I'm referring to *"I have been writing several programs during the recent two years on this system, so I am extremely desperate to get this working again"*. A machine used for professional activities which has valuable data on it gets regular backups; moreover, by its nature a machine running Kali ought to be wiped clean and reinstalled after the completion of each assignment, so that potentially confidential data from one client does not get leaked accidentally on the next client's network.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, yes, it might have been a little irrational to code security programs in Linux rather than programming them on a general-purpose OS and test them in Linux... Thanks for letting me know. Anyway, I would still love a solution to this sad, gruesome problem.

Comment: @G-Man how exactly is my question similar to the one you linked? :/

Comment: @G-Man You are doing Kali Linux effectively off-topic here. It is disastrous.

Comment: Your programs aren't lost, where did you get that idea? Just because you broke kali, by trying to do an upgrade on it, doesn't mean your data vanished. it's there, same as before. The reason you are getting no good responses is that you shouldn't have tried to upgrade a debian derived system like kali without knowing what you are doing. While I don't know the specifics of kali, I do know that there is a very simple test you can do to determine if you are running real debian: do an upgrade, then a  dist-upgrade. Not being able to do a gui login means little. Installing wine on kali, bad bad...

Comment: You should be posting this issue on Kali support forums, not here, by the way. As with Mint and other Debian derived distros, which are not actually upgradeable using Debian apt repos due to other packages which will break real Debian repo upgrades, the amount of time it would take to walk you through getting your login gui is so huge that I wouldn't personally do it for money, and certainly not for free, since this was user error in the first place.

Comment: @Lizardx, even though you did not come up with a solution for the problem, I learnt a lot - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks `autoremove` removed `libosmesa6` which may be needed, but was considered orphaned for some reason... probably wine which seemingly pulled in gphoto...

Comment: So what would you advice me to do? Thanks for taking some time to help me out!

Comment: @noflow: Try... `apt-get install libosmesa6` ...

Comment: Sadly, that did not work :( Thanks for the effort though

Comment: @noflow: I've only seen this error when I have a video driver problem... `lspci |grep VGA` and then `lsmod` looking for the matching video driver may be a good place to start.   For some reason, I've always experienced great pain when using `autoremove`, so I don't do that anymore.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I have run the commands and cannot really spot any irregularities that could cause the problem. I have updated my question with the output of those two commands. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @noflow:  It looks like you are using `virtualbox` and not a physical machine.  So, the video driver should be just fine... now what about the X11 config...  Check out the [X11 documentation](https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/7.4-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/x-config.html) and make sure that your screen `mode` is not a beyond the resolution of the virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I can confirm that my screen mode is not beyond the resolution of the VM.